# How to bind the two array results and Print it in a right output PHP

Tags: php, arrays, printing, array-merge

I have two data here:

The result of this first function:

```
Array
(
[2] => Array
    (
        [SiteID] => 2
        [Balance] => 19000.00
        [MinBalance] => 100000.00
        [MaxBalance] => 1000000.00
        [OwnerAID] => 83
        [GroupID] => 1
    )

 [3] => Array
    (
        [SiteID] => 3
        [Balance] => 94000.99
        [MinBalance] => 100000.00
        [MaxBalance] => 500000.00
        [OwnerAID] => 17
        [GroupID] => 1
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [SiteID] => 4
        [Balance] => 1000000.00
        [MinBalance] => 100000.00
        [MaxBalance] => 1000000.00
        [OwnerAID] => 12
        [GroupID] => 1
    )
```

)

The result of the second function:

```
 Array
(
 [3] => Array
    (
        [Deposit] => 459000
        [Reload] => 169100
        [Redemption] => 703576
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Deposit] => 1500
        [Reload] => 1000
        [Redemption] => 1000
    )
 )
```

Now, I need to bind the result of thie two functions, I try it with this codes:

```
    public function bindGHComponentsToSites()
    {
   error_reporting (E_ALL^ E_NOTICE);  
   $combine = array();

     foreach ($this->arrays as $keys => $data) {


       foreach($this->result as $keyss => $value){

            if($data['SiteID'] == $keyss){

                $merged = array_merge((array)$data, (array)$value);

            }
             else if ($data['SiteID'] != $keyss){

                 $val = array('Deposit'=>0, 'Reload'=>0, 'Redemption'=>0);

                 $merged = array_merge((array)$data, (array)$val);
             }

        }

              $this->combined[$data['SiteID']] = $merged;

     } 

      print_r($this->combined);
  }
```

But, I got the wrong output, the condition was, If the SiteID of bindownertosites doesn't match to the SiteId of Computeghcomponents then just print the value of the Deposit, Reload and Redemption should be equal to zero.

The Deposit, Reload and Redemption are all equal to zero which is wrong.Here's should be the right result:

```
Array
(
[2] => Array
    (
        [SiteID] => 2
        [Balance] => 19000.00
        [MinBalance] => 100000.00
        [MaxBalance] => 1000000.00
        [OwnerAID] => 83
        [GroupID] => 1
        [Deposit] => 1500
        [Reload] => 1000
        [Redemption] => 1000
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [SiteID] => 3
        [Balance] => 94000.99
        [MinBalance] => 100000.00
        [MaxBalance] => 500000.00
        [OwnerAID] => 17
        [GroupID] => 1
        [Deposit] => 459000
        [Reload] => 169100
        [Redemption] => 703576
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [SiteID] => 3
        [Balance] => 94000.99
        [MinBalance] => 100000.00
        [MaxBalance] => 500000.00
        [OwnerAID] => 17
        [GroupID] => 1
        [Deposit] => 0
        [Reload] => 0
        [Redemption] => 0
    )
  )
```

Is it possible to have this kind of result? Please help me guys, I've been working with this almost one week, but I always got a wrong output. I appreciate to your response.I put everything here to make clarify those things.Kindly review my question before you answer. Please help me and guide me in proper way. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Guys, Please help me, I know it's a little bit easier for all of you, but I'm finding out difficult.I'll appreciate your response.

Comment: I'm not getting your question, what is your expected result?

Comment: @ so geek,If the SiteID of my two functions is not equal, then just print the data of the SiteID from BindOwnerToSites and just add, the three keys Deposit, Reload and Redemption and equal the value into zero.

Comment: then the last code is the expected result? What you are getting from the combine function?

Comment: @ so geek, yes the last code, I got a wrong output, all of the value of deposit, reload, and redemption becomes zero. I don't know how will I modify the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The this will do what you expected, so simple

Try

```
foreach (array_keys($this->arrays) as $value) {
    $default = array('Deposit' => 0, 'Reload' => 0, 'Redemption' => 0);
    if (array_key_exists($value, $this->result)) {
        $temp = array_merge($this->arrays[$value], $this->result[$value]);
        $this->arrays[$value] = $temp;
    } else {
        $temp = array_merge($this->arrays[$value], $default);
        $this->arrays[$value] = $temp;
    }
}
print_r($this->arrays);
```

Comment: @ so geek, ok i'll try it. hold on. Thank you

Comment: @ so geek, there's an error, may you please plot your codes at my owned codes? thank you so much.

Comment: @Mic Look at my edited one, you need to have the loop within the `bindGHComponentsToSites()` method.

Comment: @ so geek, it works! Thank you so much. I appreciate your concern.